# Force Index in cakephp 3.3 query

Tags: mysql, cakephp, indexing, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I'm using CakePHP 3.3 and trying to fetch few statistics about revenue using the below query

```
 $this->Bookings
    ->find('all')
    ->select(['total' => 'sum(total_price)'])
    ->join($joinTables) // It has product and few other tables
    ->where(["P.id = '" . $product_id . "'"])
    ->where(["Bookings.booking_status != 'CANCELLED'"])
    ->where(["Bookings.booking_date >= '" . $last6MonthDate->format('Y-m-d') . "'"]);
```

This query uses the index on (product_id, booking_status) but, I want this query to use the index that I have created on (product_id, booking_date) which will be faster for this query. I have tried using the below line before my above query.

```
$this->Bookings->useIndex = 'FORCE INDEX(idx_product_id_booking_date)';
```

This doesn't adds the FORCE INDEX clause to my query hence, MySQL uses the index `idx_product_id_booking_status` automatically.

The answers for similar question are for previous version of CakePHP and they don't work for CakePHP 3.3. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to use index in both `select` and `join` statements:

```
$this->loadModel('MainModel');
$query = $this 
    ->MainModel
    ->select(['MainModel.id' ])
    ->from('main_model MainModel USE INDEX (PRIMARY)')
    ->join([
         'table' => 'other_model OtherModel USE INDEX (PRIMARY)',
         'conditions' => 'OtherModel.id = MainModel.other_model_id'
    ]);
```

That will produce:

```
SELECT MyModel.id
FROM my_model MyModel USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
INNER JOIN my_other_model MyOtherModel USE INDEX (PRIMARY)
ON MyModel.id = MyModel.my_model_other_id
```